# Text value of button usage in condition

Tags: java, android, if-statement, button

I'm trying to make condition where I wanto compare text value of button but it always doesn't match...

`<Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/baton1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />`

I've tried to print out the value and it shows like "[+]"...

```
if (btn.toString().equals("[+]")) {
```

Comment: try to add trim(). so if (btn.toString().trim().equals("[+]")) { .. }

Comment: very unlikely. there is a good chance that you either set the text somewhere else, or you modify the value before printing/testing it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did the necessary stuff to reach the button object from the class file.

As I know, You need to use getText() method while getting the text property of the objects.

So, you should do something like that;

```
if (btn.getText().equals("+"))
```